# Unresolved inclusion: xuartlite_l.h in Xilinx SDK

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado, xilinx-sdk

I am following [Xilinx Lab Workbook.](https://www.xilinx.com/content/dam/xilinx/training/embedded/embd/embd-sw-wkb-lab-rev1.pdf) On Lab 3 (page 60) I am supposed to have resolved all errors but I cannot get rid of an unexpected error.

"fatal error: xuartlite_l.h: No such file or directory    serialPort_helper.c    /SDKintro_app/src    line 9 "

I have regenerated BSP sources and re-built the project but nothing seems to work so far.

Comment: From a programming perspective, it just seems like you're missing a dependency. Have you verified that your libraries are in the correct location?

Comment: From what I can tell, that particular library is supposed to be built by SDK. I cannot find it anywhere in the directory. But the project is from a tutorial basically and pre-built and it apparently works for others so i don't know what is going wrong.